# .htaccess cgi perl - Invalid command 'Deny', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i'm trying to set up this: https://github.com/oprel/emanon
But everytime i try to run post.cgi i receive this error on the error log:

```
[Sat Jul 02 13:03:13.380647 2022]
/fs5d/9kun/public/board/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Deny', perhaps misspelled or 
defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The 'Invalid command' is from .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|pm)$">
deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Lines 3,4,5
What should i do?? I run apache with cgi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would expect you are on Apache 2.4

> ```
> <FilesMatch "\.(txt|pm)$">
> deny from all
> </FilesMatch>
> ```

`Deny` is an Apache 2.2 (and earlier) directive and is formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 and moved (from a *base* module) to mod_access_compat (an optional extension). This module is probably not enabled, hence the error.

You should be using the corresponding `Require` directive on Apache 2.4 instead. For example:

```
Require all denied
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not ordering the statement at all, therefore Apache has no idea whether you want to deny or allow it. Try this below...

```
<FilesMatch "\.(txt|pm)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: It does not work: `Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Comment: "Apache has no idea whether you want to deny or allow" - this is not true. In the absence of any `Order` directive, the _default_ is effectively `Order Deny,Allow`. But this is not going to make any difference unless there are additional `Allow` directives that _override_ the all encompassing `Deny from all`. However, you seem have ignored the error stated in the question: "Invalid command 'Deny'".

Comment: Tested with my live Apache server running on CentOS 7.X and worked perfectly.